# Can anyone check query I want to extract years and month columns too

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Want to extract data month wise for last 2 years. Below query actually calculating 1 month data.

[image]

```
SELECT CAST (g1.no_of_member_cancelled AS DECIMAL(10, 2)) / 
       CAST (g2.no_of_live_member AS DECIMAL(10, 2)) AS x, 
       g1.homebranch, 
       g1.locationname

FROM   (SELECT Count(*) AS No_of_Member_Cancelled, 
               M.homebranch, 
               M.locationname

        FROM   ax.memberships M 
        WHERE  M.activeend BETWEEN Dateadd(month, Datediff(month, 0, Getdate()) 
                                                  - 1, 0) 
                                   AND 
                                           Dateadd(month, Datediff(month, 0, 
                                                          Getdate()) 
                                           , -1) 
        GROUP  BY M.homebranch, 
                  M.locationname) AS g1 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT Count(*)AS No_of_Live_Member, 
                          M.homebranch, 
                          M.locationname

                   FROM   ax.memberships M 
                   WHERE  M.activestart BETWEEN Dateadd(month, Datediff(month, 0 
                                                               , 
                                                               Getdate()) - 1, 
                                                0) AND 
                          Dateadd(month, Datediff(month, 
                                         0, Getdate( 
                                         )), -1) 
                   GROUP  BY M.homebranch, 
                             M.locationname
                             ) AS g2 
               ON g1.homebranch = g2.homebranch 
                  AND g1.locationname = g2.locationname
```

Want to extract data month wise for last 2 years. Below query actually calculating 1 month data.

Comment: Give some sample data and expected result.

Comment: https://ibb.co/f2NZMTW

Comment: actually I want to extract data month wise.

Comment: replace -1 with -24

Comment: But I have to display with each month and year.

Comment: Show us which format your data in your table.